# WebStorm : How to import multiple project in same window in WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

Need help to figure out how to import multiple projects in same window in WebStorm, In IntelliJ we can do this using modules, But I don't see that feature in WebStorm.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

WebStorm [doesn't support](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-15187) opening multiple projects in the same frame, however you can add multiple **content roots** to the same project:

[image: add content root]

Comment: AFAIK [IDEABKL-6118](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6118) is for IntelliJ IDEA only. Maybe [WI-15187](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-15187) can also be applied to WebStorm?

Answer (score 39):

From Webstorm 2019.2 - you can open multiple projects in the same Webstorm instance.

File --> Open --> Go to the project directory --> Open:
In the Open Project dialog , select "Attach".

[image]

Comment: Just in case anybody is wondering, when you attach a project like that, it will be attached forever (even if you close and reopen the project) until you detach it. To detach, you have to click on the project and hit "delete"

Comment: Adding to @AndréPena's comment: Right click the project (in the project view) and choose "remove from project view" or press <kbd>del</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Webstorm supports opening two projects in one window now.

All you have to do is open first project then

File --> Open --> Select second project folder and click open --> Then click **Attach** from the next dialog box

**This is working in Ubuntu**

Answer (score 0):

On Newer versions of WebStorm (eg WebStorm 2022.1.1)

From the top options.
`File -> Attach project... -> Select project folder -> Click Open`

This will "Add" the selected project folder into the workspace.